# React not displaying images after deploy

Tags: reactjs

I created a react app and it looked good , until I deployed it. After deployment, i cannot see the images, even if react loads them (i see that in the networking tab on chrome). Also the Content type was set right. Also when i go directly to the miage links, chrome renderes them.

This is the component responsable for showing the images:

```
import "./../styles/firstPart.css";
import logo from "./../images/croped_down.png";
import background from "./../images/background.jpg";
import PreloadImage from "react-preload-image";
import Navbar from "./../components/navbar";

const FirstPart = () => {
  return (
    <div className="firstPart">
      <div className="mainGradient"></div>
      <PreloadImage className="background" src={background} />
      <PreloadImage className="logo" src={logo} />
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  );
};

export default FirstPart;
```

Comment: Please share some more information about what you are seeing. If the images are not loading appropriately, there must be some error.

Comment: Pls attach code to debug. there would be many cases of not showing images on prod

Comment: @tomerpacific i literarly dont see the images , the images are loaded , but not displayed. I would share a link of the page , but i dont know if it is ok here

Comment: @ByrisettiHemanth i edited the post and ive added the code responsable for displaying the images

Comment: update, now i realised that i can see the image , but it is verry verry dimm. I tryed adjusting the css, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Image path is relative and works for local. The same won't be working in prod as it takes absolute page. Check the path of image in Developer Console and see if the path is same as existed

Comment: the path to the image is fine, and also react loads it , but it doesnt display .